# When the negative number appears first time

Tags: javascript, count

Im new to the javascript, so I decided to ask here. I have a problem with little javascript that shows where will the lift stop(which floor). It starts on the floor 0, and every U means UP and every D means DOWN. So this is what I have.

```
    <script language="JavaScript">

 var temp = "UUDDUDUUDUDUDUDUDUDUDDD"; //

var hore = (temp.match(/U/g) || []).length;      //UP
var dole = (temp.match(/D/g) || []).length;      //DOWN

pociatocne_poschodie = 0;
vytah_zastavil = (hore - dole) + pociatocne_poschodie;

document.write(vytah_zastavil);

 </script>
```

It works very well, but I need to output when was the lift in the basement first time(After how many steps).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: why you are doing `+ pociatocne_poschodie`? Always is 0...

Comment: What do you mean by basement? `-1` ?

Comment: its because of possible change, I know its always 0 even without fixing it to 0

Comment: Well, you can iterate through the `temp` vector, start with `var floor = 0` if you encounter `U` do `floor++` otherwise `floor--`, when `floor === -1` print the current position in the temp vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if this is what you require, you would need to change the log to document.write currently gets the first -1 at 23 steps

```js
var temp = "UUDDUDUUDUDUDUDUDUDUDDD"; 

var floor = 0;

for (var i = 0; i<temp.length; i++){
  var c = temp.charAt(i);
  if(c === "U"){
    floor++;
  }
  if(c === "D"){
    floor--;
  }
  if(floor === -1){
    document.write("reached basement in " + (i+1) + " steps");
  }  
}
```

Comment: added i+1 for steps, didnt count first as an actual step since it was 0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! Thats what I needed!

```js
var temp = "UUDDUDUUDUDUDUDUDUDUDDD"; 

var floor = 0;

for (var i = 0; i<temp.length; i++){
  var c = temp.charAt(i);

  if(c === "U"){
    floor++;
  }
  if(c === "D"){
    floor--;
  }
  if(floor === -1){
    console.log("reached basement in " + i + "steps");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Peter, welcome to StackOverflow. If answer by user2950720 is fine, please accept his/her answer, and don't replicate it again as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = "UUDDUDUUDUDUDUDUDUDUDDD"; //

var count = 0;
var basement = -1;

var step;

for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    if (temp[i] == "U") {
        count += 1
    } else if (temp[i] == "D") {
        count -= 1
    }
    if (count == basement) {
        step = i;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(step);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution with various examples.

I hope that helps you.

```js
function getStepsToStopInBasement(liftSteps) {
  var currentFloor = 0;
  var steps;

  for (var i = 0; i < liftSteps.length && !steps; i += 1) {
    switch (liftSteps.charAt(i)) {
      //UP
      case "U":
        currentFloor += 1;
        break;
        //DOWN
      case "D":
        currentFloor -= 1;
        break;
    }
    //CHECK BASEMENT
    if (currentFloor === -1) {
      steps = i;
    }
  }
  return steps;
}

console.log(getStepsToStopInBasement("UUDDUDUUDUDUDUDUDUDUDDD")); //22
console.log(getStepsToStopInBasement("UUDDUDUUDUDUDUDUDDD")); //18
console.log(getStepsToStopInBasement("UUDDUDDUDUDUDUDUDUDDD")); //6
console.log(getStepsToStopInBasement("UUDDUDUUDUDUDUDUDUDUDDD")); //22
console.log(getStepsToStopInBasement("UUDDUDUDDD")); //8
```